# openGL, the inverse of the transformations

Tags: matrix, opengl, transformation

If I have 3 different matrices, one for rotation (R), one for translation(T), and one for scaling (S), how to achieve the reverse effect of these matrices by manipulating the one caused it?

What I gathered so far is if I transposed the rotation matrix, I will achieve what I desire (is this correct?). And what about the other two?
And if there is a common way, are there any special cases where these ways will not suffice?

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of the rotation matrix **R** is indeed its transpose **R<sup>T</sup>**.

The inverse of the scaling matrix **S** is easy as it contains only diagonal elements (the first three rows, as the last row is always equals to `(0 0 0 1)`)

So you just replace each diagonal **s<sub>i</sub>** with **1/s<sub>i</sub>**.

Finally the translation matrix **T** is an identity matrix with the translation vector on the last column. The inverse is achieved by replacing those elements with their negative.

Also the inverse of the product of 3 matrices, is the reverse product

**(S T R)<sup>-1</sup>** = **R<sup>-1</sup> T<sup>-1</sup> S<sup>-1</sup>**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what about the special cases where these operations will not produce the reverse effect but other weird effect. I am only asking because I found this question in an exercise sheet.

Comment: I don't understand. What other weird effect are you referring to?

Comment: i really don't know , the question just says " how to acheive the reverse effect and what are the special cases where your solution won't suffice?